# Debugging Rails 3.2 failing to precompile ember-rails 0.19

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ember.js, asset-pipeline, sprockets, ember-rails

Looking for a way to determine where in my code or in the ember-rails/ember-rails-source this error is coming from. Using rails 3.2 and the latest ember-rails 0.19. When I precompile my assets I get this failure:

```
Unexpected token: operator (!) (line: 16, col: 178179, pos: 178546)

Error
    at new JS_Parse_Error (<eval>:3096:22)
    at js_error (<eval>:3104:15)
    at croak (<eval>:3557:17)
    at token_error (<eval>:3564:17)
    at unexpected (<eval>:3570:17)
    at Object.semicolon [as 1] (<eval>:3590:51)
    at prog1 (<eval>:4133:29)
    at simple_statement (<eval>:3726:35)
    at <eval>:3634:35
    at block_ (<eval>:3822:32)
  (in /Users/sjustin/Development/my-app/app/assets/javascripts/application.js.coffee)
```

I've been able to destructively get the assets to precompile by removing the Ember Sprockets reference, `#= require ember` in my `application.js.coffee`:

```
#= require jquery
#= require jquery_ujs
#= require ember
#= require ember-data
#= require_self
#= require my-app

window.MyApp = Ember.Application.create()
```

But that breaks the app. If I run the app locally without precompiling I don't get any errors from Rails or the JavaScript console.

Answer (score 0):

Which javascript runtime (e.g. `therubyracer`, `execjs`, `nodejs`) are you using? Have you tried to switch it? I'd recommend using node (especially if you're running multiple apps on a single server), because you don't have to add a gem if node is installed.

Comment: Interesting. I didn't notice this before but we're using `therubyracer` in the main default Gemfile group and `execjs` in the assets Gemfile group. I wasn't setting the group when I was trying to precompile, wondering if it has something to do with that. Going to check it out.

Comment: Same issue using all three, output all similar but execjs gives me a file output where it failed: `at new JS_Parse_Error (/private/var/folders/rl/5q_8gb4s453fwpy1wnb7cpd52cpx91/T/execjs20150715-72034-17hdmvr.js:3096:22)` Doesn't help though because it's gone before I can look at it.

Comment: Can you try calling `rake assets:precompile` on your development environment? And - just to be sure - are there any JS errors in your browsers development tools when opening the site locally?

Comment: `rake assets:precompile` fails locally with the same error, but `RAILS_ENV=development rake assets:precompile` does NOT fail. If I do NOT precompile and run the app there are no errors. But if I run it with `RAILS_ENV=development` I get a blank page with `Uncaught ReferenceError: MyApp is not defined` in the console all over the place. Thanks for the responses!

Comment: Too many things stirring the pot made this problem very confusing, thanks for all your help! Our application had `config.assets.compress = true` in `config/environments/production.rb` only. When I ran `RAILS_ENV=development rake assets:precompile` the console errors were due to assets expecting to be served up via Nginx, and not the asset pipeline during requests. Long story short, there's an error someplace in the JavaScript resulting in an error ONLY during compression. And unless you set the environment the default is production.

Comment: My next proposal would have been to detect differences between your environments ;) So now you know which of your js files caused the error? If not, try to play around with this settings:   `config.assets.compress`, `config.assets.digest`,  `config.assets.debug` (they're all booleans). I've experienced  some strange behaviours (depending on the OS, Rails version, etc.; hard to reproduce) depending those values while using Rails 3.